# operation '*' cannot be applied to operand of type 'int' and 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand'

Tags: c#, sql, azure

I'm trying to call value from my table in sql azure therefore i did a connection between my webservice and my sql azure. I added a connectionstring into my web.config to establish connection

```
<connectionStrings>
 <add name="ConnectionString"connectionString="Server=tcp:vvigan1a71.database.windows.net,1433;Database=(myname);User  ID=(myid);Password=(myownpassword);Trusted_Connection=False;Encrypt=True;" />
</connectionStrings>
```

I then tried to link  azure via my connectionstring in my web service file.

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
```

I added a datareader to read data from my sql azure and call the value and use it like shown below

```
public double CarTaxwithOMV(int carValue)
    {

        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand taxafter30k = new SqlCommand("Select taxafter30k from TaxValue");
        SqlCommand taxafter50k = new SqlCommand("Select taxafter50k from TaxValue");
        SqlDataReader dr;

        dr = taxafter30k.ExecuteReader();
        dr = taxafter50k.ExecuteReader();

        if (dr.Read())
        {
            double totalcartaxOMV = 0d;

            if (carValue <= 20000)
            {
                totalcartaxOMV = carValue;
            }
            else if (carValue > 20000 && carValue <= 50000)
            {
                totalcartaxOMV = ((20000 + ((carValue - 20000) * taxafter30k)));
            }
            else if (carValue > 50000)
            {
                totalcartaxOMV = (20000 + 42000 + ((carValue - 50000) * taxafter50k));
            }
            con.Close();
            return totalcartaxOMV;
        }
    }
```

However, at my

```
totalcartaxOMV = ((20000 + ((carValue - 20000) * taxafter30k)));
```

i received this error

```
operation '*' cannot be applied to operand of type 'int' and 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand'
```

Unfortunately, this seems to be the only way to connect and get data from my sql azure and using it.

Comment: No, trying to multiple a `SqlCommand` by an integer is *not* the only way to get data. You need to *execute* the command and then extract the data from it. You're already executing both commands, and storing the result in `dr`... although that means you're throwing away the data from `taxAfter30k`. Then again, you're not actually using the data in `dr` either... you're only referring to it in `dr.Read()`, but not getting the values. Basically this code is badly broken, and you should look at it *very* closely. You may well want to have a *single* command which fetches both columns, for example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cant use taxafter30k, its an SqlCommand

Your code should be

```
 totalcartaxOMV = ((20000 + ((carValue - 20000) * Convert.ToDouble(
 dr["taxafter30k"])));
```

or replace with

```
    SqlCommand taxafter30k = new SqlCommand("Select taxafter30k from TaxValue");
    SqlCommand taxafter50k = new SqlCommand("Select taxafter50k from TaxValue");
    SqlDataReader dr;

    double taxafter30kNew = Convert.ToDouble(taxafter30k.ExecuteScalar());
    double taxafter30kNew = Convert.ToDouble(taxafter50k.ExecuteScalar());


        double totalcartaxOMV = 0d;

        if (carValue <= 20000)
        {
            totalcartaxOMV = carValue;
        }
        else if (carValue > 20000 && carValue <= 50000)
        {
            totalcartaxOMV = ((20000 + ((carValue - 20000) * taxafter30kNew)));
        }
        else if (carValue > 50000)
        {
            totalcartaxOMV = (20000 + 42000 + ((carValue - 50000) * taxafter50kNew));
        }
        con.Close();
        return totalcartaxOMV;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change taxafter30k  to

`(double)dr["taxafter30k"]`

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
dr = taxafter30k.ExecuteReader();
```

will return a result set which you have to navigate through, not a single result.
Using Intellisense you should be able to easily find the methods you need or revert to another execute method.

For a single scalar result use:

```
dr = taxafter30k.ExecuteScalar();
```

You'll have to adapt your query accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

"taxafter30k" is a SQLDataReader.
You need to retrieve the value from the SQLDataReader (assuming it's an int):

```
int tax = 0;
if( taxafer30k.Read() )
{
   tax = taxafter30k.GetInt32(0);
}
```

Then use the "tax" variable in your calculation;